# How to subset a list based on its elements - R

Tags: r

I would like to select a subset of a list based on the value of the elements.
I thought this would be simple, and I think I'm close-ish. But I need some help.

I have a list of 'features' ChemFeats.all:

```
> str(ChemFeats.all)
List of 20
 $ HPh_feats       : chr [1:4] "f_225" "f_3006" "f_2876" "f_2480"
 $ PhCN_feats      : chr "f_3285"
 $ PhCA_feats      : chr [1:2] "f_2477" "f_189"
 $ PYO_feats       : chr "f_3284"
 $ HHQ_feats       : chr [1:5] "f_3001" "f_750" "f_589" "f_186" ...
 $ PQS_feats       : chr [1:4] "f_2334" "f_2" "f_185" "f_408"
```

And I have a vector of "good" features:

```
> str(gd_feats)
 chr [1:43] "f_649" "f_70" "f_711" "f_748" "f_3" "f_414" "f_2181" ...
```

Now I want a subset of the first list only containing the good features.
Here is one of my attempts, I have tried a few similar versions, some being closer than others.

```
ChemFeats.all.GdFts<-lapply(ChemFeats.all, '[',function(x) match(x, gd_feats))
```

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Features don't repeat within an element of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
lapply(ChemFeats.all, function(y) gd_feats[gd_feats %in% y])
```

Comment: More natural would be `y[y %in% gd_feats]` in case `y` has repeating values. And if there are no repeating values, `intersect` is an option.

Comment: Thanks. this worked and I used y[y %in% gd_feats] seemed to make more sense

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to do this properly, lapply is the right way to go. The problem is that lists are just that - lists. Think of them as collections of other types of object (you can get lists of vectors or lists of data.frames or lists of lists), which means that finding individual values is hard for functions like subset() because it's ambiguous as to whether you want "values within the objects in the list that have $VALUE" or "entire objects in the value" or...so on, so forth.

The way I'd do it is something like:

```
good_chemfeats <- lapply(ChemFeats.all, function(features, good_features){
     return(features[features %in% good_features])
}, good_features = gd_feats)
```

What this will do is, for each vector in the list, check whether that vector contains any good features. If it does, it'll return them. Presumably the reason you're not just unlisting it and doing a simple %in% is that you'd like to preserve the list names, which this method *should* do.